# jQuery event bubbling: How to capture a nested click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm capturing a click on any given LI in:

```
<ul>
    <li class="opt">Text 1</li>
    <li class="opt">Text 2</li>
</ul>
```

With the code:

```
$('.opt').live('click', function(event) {
    console.log("Click!");
}
```

and it works wonderfully :)  However, I also need to support the ability for nested block elements to exist inside the LI, without changing my javascript code.  The above javascript does *not* fire when Text 1 in clicked in this case:

```
<ul>
    <li class="opt">
        <div>
            <div>
                <span>Text 1</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've read that jQuery events "bubble up" through the DOM, but unfortunately no such bubbling is occurring here.  What's the cleanest way to capture a click event inside an LI when I'm not sure of what other elements might be inside of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a dot on that class selector, then it should work:

```
$('.opt').live('click', function(event) {
    console.log("Click!");
}
```

Unless you're doing something abnormal (e.g. `.stopPropogation()` on a clicked child), the event should bubble right up all by itself.

Comment: My fault -- I have the dot there in my code, but lost it in translation.  Even with that, my event doesn't seem to be firing a few layers up.

Comment: @Tom - It fires fine here in all tests...there's something else going on, do you have a test page I can look at?

Comment: Oh my is this ever a facepalm moment.  The event was bubbling up fine -- it was my misinterpretation of where event.target points that caused my code to halt.  Not a total waste of time though, since I wouldn't have found that error if not for your comments.  Thanks, Nick!

Comment: @Tom - That happens to me at least 3 times a week :) Glad you got it working!

Comment: @TomFrost: you might want to edit the original post in order to save occasional readers the time; at the current state it says nothing about the real problem, and one has to read not only the selected answer but also its comments in order to understand that the problem is not in the least related to the title or to the post!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.opt, .opt *').live('click', function(event) {
    console.log("Click!");
}
```

Comment: This isn't a great idea, you're going to fire that event a *lot* of times, 1 for each nested element.